# c# fetch data from this two dates IN ACCESS

Tags: c#, datetime, ms-access

I’m fetch data from this two dates and date format is custom like this dd/MM/yyyy.. both but not show accurate answer between this two dates

Ther is my code :

```
  private void LoadDataGg()
    {
      LoadDataGridView.DataSource = Getdatlisttt();
    }
 private DataTable Getdatlisttt()
   {
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppLogin"].ConnectionString;
     string cmdstring = "SELECT FROM ClientRecord WHERE DATE1 >='" + DTpickerfrom.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'
     AND DATE1<='" + DTpickerTo.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "' ";
      using (OleDbConnection con11 = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
       {
           using (OleDbCommand cmd11 = new OleDbCommand(cmdstring, con11))
         {
             con11.Open();
             OleDbDataReader reader = cmd11.ExecuteReader();
             dt.Load(reader);
            con11.Close();
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Sooo... what exactly is your question?

Comment: What is your problem

Comment: but it not show accurate answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date values don't hold a format, but as string expression in SQL they must, and you should use the ISO sequence: yyyy-mm-dd. Thus:

```
 string cmdstring = "SELECT FROM ClientRecord WHERE DATE1 >= #" + DTpickerfrom.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# AND DATE1 <= #" + DTpickerTo.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#";
```